# Prove that a weighted series converges to zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_k$ be such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k<\infty$. Let $b_n$ be such that  $b_n\rightarrow\infty$. I need to prove that

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{b_n}\,\sum_{k=0}^{b_n}k\,a_k= 0. \quad (1)
$$

In particular I think that there exist conditions on the rate of divergence of the $b_n$'s to $+\infty$ that allow (1) to hold. I am pretty confident that there exist some results in the literature.

Comment: Is the term in the sum supposed to be $b_n$ or $b_k$ ?

Comment: I suppose that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):b_n\in\mathbb{N}$. Am I right?

Comment: The term is $b_n$ not $b_k$. Yes, I think you can assume $b_n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You need to tell us more. What does $\sum a_k < \infty $ even mean? Does it mean the series converges? If so, say so. Are the $b_n$ integers? If so, say so. Also note limits don't $\to 0,$ although they may equal $0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If you put $S_m=\sum_{k=0}^m a_k$, then the sequence to study is
 $$T_n=S_{b_n}-\frac{S_0+\cdots+S_{b_n}}{b_n}$$ (use that $S_0=a_0$ and $a_k=S_k-S_{k-1}$ for $k\geq 1$) Now as $S_{b_n}\to L$, use Cesaro's theorem.

Comment: I did not understand very well your idea. Does it work for $a_k=1/k$ ? Because in this case for sure the (1) does not hold.

Comment: @AlmostSureUser The series $a_k=1/k$ is not convergent.

Comment: yes sorry. Now it is clear.

Comment: You are welcome.